# Close the login page in javafx when open a new stage

Tags: javafx

Hi I am creating a login page and a dashboard page I want to close or hide my login page and Show Dashboard When I Click on Login Button. but its not working

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUser;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField txtPassword;
    @FXML
    private Label message;
    @FXML
    private Label lblUser;
    @FXML
    private Label lblPassword;
    @FXML
    private void OpenDashBoard(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FxmlMethods object = new FxmlMethods();
        // showFxml method usd for open a new window named DashBoard.fxml
        object.showFxml("/DashBoard/DashBoard.fxml", "/ DashBoard/DashboardStyle.css", "Dash Board");

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

And My Main Class is :

```
public class DATACOLLECTION extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/icon.png"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Login");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.show();
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

please help me

Comment: No one know __FxmlMethods__. If you can access the stage, you can simply replace the current scene with the login page by another scene with dashboard.

Comment: Explain "its not working". What happens? Do you get an error? (If so, post the stack trace.)

Comment: Please check bellow answer.

Comment: If you need to manage multiple screens in JavaFX, then [JavaFX Data Flow API](http://www.javafxdata.org/overview_flow.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this and its working Thanks to all for your Response.

```
 @FXML
    private void CloseAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) Close.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
```